# save canvas as image with rotated elements

Tags: javascript, canvas

i would like to save a canvas to an image with canvas.toDataURL("image/png") which works like a charm escept when i rotate images and text it does not work properly.

when i rotate a text like 20° or whatever and save the canvas, every single character is rotated 20° instead of the whole text.

when i do the same with an image, nothing happens at all. the image saved is just not rotated.

is there some kind of workaround or is it just technically not possible?

thanks for any help :)

---

this is how i save the canvas;

```
 $('#target').html2canvas({
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
            }
        });
```

this is the function fo the html2canvas;

```
/**
  @license html2canvas v0.34 <http://html2canvas.hertzen.com>
  Copyright (c) 2011 Niklas von Hertzen. All rights reserved.
  http://www.twitter.com/niklasvh

  Released under MIT License
 */
/*
 * jQuery helper plugin for examples and tests
 */
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.html2canvas = function(options) {
        if (options && options.profile && window.console && window.console.profile) {
            console.profile();
        }
        var date = new Date(),
        html2obj,
        $message = null,
        timeoutTimer = false,
        timer = date.getTime();
        options = options || {};

        options.onrendered = options.onrendered || function( canvas ) {
            var $canvas = $(canvas),
            finishTime = new Date();

            if (options && options.profile && window.console && window.console.profileEnd) {
                console.profileEnd();
            }
            $canvas.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            }).appendTo(document.body);
            $canvas.siblings().toggle();

            $(window).click(function(){
                $canvas.toggle().siblings().toggle();
                throwMessage("Canvas Render " + ($canvas.is(':visible') ? "visible" : "hidden"));
            });
            throwMessage('Screenshot created in '+ ((finishTime.getTime()-timer)) + " ms<br />",4000);

            // test if canvas is read-able
            try {
                $canvas[0].toDataURL();
            } catch(e) {
                if ($canvas[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() === "canvas") {
                    // TODO, maybe add a bit less offensive way to present this, but still something that can easily be noticed
                    alert("Canvas is tainted, unable to read data");
                }
            }
        };

        html2obj = html2canvas(this, options);

        function throwMessage(msg,duration){
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
            timeoutTimer = window.setTimeout(function(){
                $message.fadeOut(function(){
                    $message.remove();
                    $message = null;
                });
            },duration || 2000);
            if ($message)
                $message.remove();
            $message = $('<div />').html(msg).css({
                margin:0,
                padding:10,
                background: "#000",
                opacity:0.7,
                position:"fixed",
                top:10,
                right:10,
                fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
                color:'#fff',
                fontSize:12,
                borderRadius:12,
                width:'auto',
                height:'auto',
                textAlign:'center',
                textDecoration:'none',
                display:'none'
            }).appendTo(document.body).fadeIn();
            html2obj.log(msg);
        }
    };
})( jQuery );
```

for the rotation i use this;
http://godswearhats.com/jquery-ui-rotatable/demo.html

Comment: Can you include `html`, `css`, `javascript` that you have tried at Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please give some example or jsfiddle

Comment: html2canvas is not able to render every CSS rules, particularly this old version you are using. You should first try with the [latest version available](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/tag/0.5.0-alpha1) even if still in "pre-release" status, it adds a lot of bug fixes.

Comment: thanks latest version was a good point :-) didnt change anything tho :/

Comment: well maybe as you say, it is just not possible to render it. would there be another way to make something like a "screenshot" of a page due html/js. the thing is it is part of a konfiguration tool and i would like to save the image as it is so a external screenshot tool is no solution :-/ saving the position of the divs and the rotation and everything might be one workaround but not what i actually want

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle or plnkr http://plnkr.co of current implementation?